# help in "more work than he can help"

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-meaning

The Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary gives the following example sentence, along with its interpretation in brackets:

> He never does more work than he can help (= he does as little as possible) .

Actually, the problem lies not so much with the meaning of "help" as with the structure.

Consider a structurally identical sentence:

> He never does more work than he is given.

That means, for example, that if he is given 10 pieces of work, he will not do an eleventh. He only does what he is asked to do.

Back to the OP sentence. Suppose "help" means "avoid." Then the original sentence can be rephrased as below:

> He never does more work than he can avoid (doing).

Bearing in mind that it means "he does as little as possible," we can see the puzzle is that the intended interpretation is actually the *reverse* of the above sentence:

> He never does more work than he **cannot avoid (doing)**.

I.e., he never does more work than he has to do; he only does as much as he has to do.

Comment: Think of it as *He never does more work than he can help **doing**.* If he can't help doing [more of] something, that means he ***does*** do it (he has no choice in the matter).

Comment: "How does it come about?" questions are off-topic here, since they can get into etymology. ELU is better for that. But the verb **help** can be reflexive (and that meaning can survive in set phrases  even where the reflexive pronoun has fallen away over time)  and then it has the  meaning "to act on one's own behalf or in one's own interest, or volitionally".

Comment: Please see the edit to my question.

Comment: -1. Your example with **is given** is hardly "structurally identical'.

Comment: The edit turns it from what felt like an answerable question to not really a question at all.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Identical in relevant ways, at least.

Answer (score 6):

***Late Edit:***
I see from comments & other answers there is still potential for some confusion with the word "help" in this context.

**It has no connection to "assisting"**
It does **not** share meaning with 'Can you help me fix this?'
'Help' has two completely distinct meanings.
Original answer below...

---

> He never does more work than he can help (= he does as little as possible) .

Read it as

> He never does more work than he can **avoid having to do**.

Consider...

> I can't help falling over in these roller skates.

Being a poor skater, you can't do any better than constantly fall; you can't help falling; you can't avoid falling.

'Help' in such circumstances is safer to read as **avoid**, which then carries exactly the same meaning from being a poor skater to being adept at not doing any work, unless you must.

Comment: Please see the edit to my question.

Comment: But the problem with "help" understood as "avoid" in this context is that it is not amenable to logical analysis. If a person avoids 20 pieces of work but does 19 a day, he fits into the scenario described by the sentence, "He never does more work than he can avoid (doing)." But that hardly means he does as little work as possible.

Comment: Yes it does. It just means "as little as possible == 19" for that particular scenario.

Comment: That really depends on the nature of his work. It is not inconceivable to suppose , for some professions, the majority of requests would be turned down. 19 would be considered a lot.

Comment: Does "He never does more work than he can avoid, but he always does as much as he can" seem like a self-contradiction?

Comment: Stop trying to qualify it with a number; it doesn't work. & yes, your last post is completely contradictory. This is partly why I used the skater analogy - the skater is always going to try as hard as possible to not fall; which removes any element of 'choosing how much not to fall'.

Comment: But there is something tricky when "help" in the sense of "avoid" is used in a comparative structure. In "He never does more work than he can help," the amount of work he does is a subset of, or limited to, the amount of work he has to do, so the OP sentence actually is equivalent to "He never does more work than he **cannot avoid** doing," i.e.; he never does more work than has to do.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's what I've been saying all along.

Comment: Well, in your answer you said, "He never does more work than he can **avoid having to do**.

Answer (score 5):

to help [doing something] means: it's beyond your abilities to do something; usually used in the negative.

**I can't help doing this.** [is typical usage; it is beyond my abilities to not do this]

He never does more work than he can help [doing].

In other words, he never does more work than what is beyond his abilities.

Comment: Sorry, but I disagree. To me it reads as 'he tries to avoid doing anything'; which also agrees with the dictionary definition.

Comment: I disagree as well - to me it means that he shirks his duties as much as possible. It's similar to "not if I can help it", which roughly means "I'm not going to do it".

Comment: @Dr Sitecore What I said is not really in contradiction with what you both are saying. He avoids it because he can't help it. It it beyond his abilities, literally, to do more. I can't help pointing this out. [It is beyond my abilities to not point this out.]

Comment: @Lambie Ok, your point is well taken :)

Comment: I agree with Lambie here, and *disagree* with the two comments above. Pragmatically, OP's text pretty much ***entails*** (stronger than simply ***implies***) that he does do at least ***some*** work. But it's only an "implication" (not necessarily true) that the subject would prefer to do *no work at all* if that option were available.

Comment: There's no 'implication' of 'as little as possible' [which incidentally includes 'none'] because it's stated in the OP.

Comment: @AmirhoseinRiazi come  close to **doing** something.

Comment: I wonder if it means "He comes close to doing something, but it[the act of helping]'s impossible for him." or "He's already helped us, but not to the extent that is expected."  or "He can help us, but he doesn't" or none of them.

Comment: I think the phrase "If [one] can help it" is informative here.  Another rephrasing along the lines in this answer might be "He never does work if he can help it, but can't always".

Answer (score 1):

He never does more work than he can help (himself by doing).

He does no more than the work required to help himself.

Comment: Your answer makes perfect sense if "help" means, as you say, "to act on one's own behalf or in one's own interest, or volitionally". But the Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary lists the OP sentence in its illustration of "can / cannot help" and defines "help" as "avoid or prevent."

Comment: https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/help_1?q=help

Comment: @Apollyon: I think you do not understand what dictionaries are. You seem to treat them as if God himself had written them, that their formulations are the only way of understanding a word and represent an exhaustive set of possibilities. Especially with a learner's dictionary, a definition is merely a way to help a learner get a handle on how a word is used. Some lexicographers might say "Used to indicate that a person tends to avoid work".

Comment: Are you suggesting the OP sentence is actually a misplacement in the said entry?

Comment: I don't know what sentence you're referring to and I have no idea what you mean by **misplacement**. I mean you should cease to be a slave to a single dictionary.

Comment: I'm referring to" He never does more work than he can help (= he does as little as possible) ." If it doesn't illustrate the sense of "avoid" or "prevent," isn't it a misplacement?

Comment: I'm saying that "avoid" is only a paraphrase of the meaning. It merely nibbles at the edges of the  meaning. In context, it's a decent paraphrase.  But there's nothing about the verb **help** itself which has anything to do with "avoid". *He never read more dictionaries than he could help.*

Comment: What's the object of "help" in your last example?

Comment: It is (vestigially) reflexive.

Comment: There is something special about the OP sentence. "Help" in the sense of "avoid" is rather tricky when used in a comparative structure. In "He never does more work than he can help," the amount of work he does is a subset of, or limited to, the amount of work he has to do, so the OP sentence actually is equivalent to "He never does more work than he **cannot avoid** doing," i.e.; he never does more work than has to do.

Comment: **Help** does not have the sense "avoid".

Comment: Maybe "more X than one can help" is an idiom?